# boost induce maximum common subgraph

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph, boost-graph

I want to induce a small graph on a large graph. Both of these graphs are shown bellow. The vertices with same color are equivalent.

[image: small]
small graph (subject to be induced)
[image: large]
large graph (The smaller graph is induced on)

---

The problem is none of the red vertices on the large graph have 4 neighbors as the small graph. So `boost::vf2_subgraph_iso` would fail inducing `small` on the `large`. But If the inducing algorithm is more tolerant (maximal matching instead of matching all vertices) then it may yield a closest match.

On the other hand `boost::mcgregor_common_subgraphs` takes really exponentially long time to complete. The other consequence is applying Maximum Common Subgraph finding algorithm on, two absolutely incompatible graphs is wastage of huge amount of CPU time. mcgregor's algorithm is based on finding cliques. So it starts with 1 vertex subgraph aand progresses towards larger subgraphs. For a subgraph hving more than 10 vertices it takes unacceptable amount of time to reach to the obvious solution.

So What is the solution in this scenario ? Is there a more tolerant algorithm for inducing subgraph ?

Comment: Would mcgregor even consider that a match? It seems to me graph isomorphism is pretty well-defined, and your samples just aren't. That makes the solution non-obvious to me. Maybe you can devise your own heuristic to merge some "equivalent nodes" prior to matching?